# tableToGrid jqgrid sortable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a  which has 3 columns and using jqgrid I am converting it to jqgrid table. This piece of line does the trick:

```
tableToGrid("#gasolineProducts", { width: '400', height: 'auto', caption: ''});
```

However my all columns are now sortable. I don't want my 3rd column to be sortable. How can I specify that in here?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) parameter as additional option of the `tableToGrid` (in the second parameter) in the same way as you would do this if you create jqGrid directly. `sortable:false` value in the corresponding column will make the corresponding column non-sortable.

One more option would be to define [onSortCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event handler which tests the `index` or `iCol` parameters to decide which column header is clicked by the user. You can return `'stop'` string to deny sorting of the 3rd column.